# Disable soft Input keyboard for searchview

Tags: java, android, mono, keyboard, searchview

I am showing a custom made keyboard for a searchview and suppress the default soft input keyboard. It works well except when I try to pull the navigation drawer and release it, the default soft input keyboard is shown. How do I disable the default soft keyboard for an actionbar searchview or maybe a particular activity? So far I have tried the following without success

- Setting Activity's `WindowSoftInputMode` to `StateAlwaysHidden`
- Setting the SearchView's input type to `NULL`
- Get the underlying `EditText` behind the `SearchView` and added an `OnTouchListener`and Hide the default soft keyboard with `InputMethodManager`

Note: I am using Mono Android and I can understand Java code so please don't hesitate to give any Java solutions.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Toggle keyboard If the keyboard is visible,then hidden it,if it's
 * invisible,then show it
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public static void toggleKeyboard(Context context) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if (imm.isActive()) {
        imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT,
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}

/**
 * Hide keyboard
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context,IBinder token) {
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    if(imm.isActive()){
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(token,0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using methods similar to this to hide the default keyboard. But i don't know which event triggers the default keyboard to show up when the application is out of focus Ex: When pulling down the notification bar, low battery alert, etc

Comment: To special view,I think is `OnFocusChangeListener`.If you want to find the global event of it,I don't know.

Comment: Tried it with that as well. Didn't work. Thanks for the input though